# Find the missing Item in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

There is a sequence described below.What is the missing item?

---

$5,10,?,50,122,...$

Comment: I am not sure (since I am not active on that site), but [puzzling.SE has a tag](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence) for this type of question. So it might be a possible place to ask such questions. (Maybe the experienced users of that site would be able to give better advice on what kind of questions is suitable there.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2^2+1,3^2+1 , .., 7^2+1, 11^2+1$, seems like series of primes to me so I would guess 26

Answer (score 0):

It must be zero, and the sequence is, of course, $$5,10,0,50,122,0,5,10,0,50,122,0,5,10,0,\dots$$

Comment: Why do you say *must*, you could have said maybe 0 out of many possibilities

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi It's an everyday 'must', not a formal mathematical conclusion. This 'must' means 'it's pretty obvious to me'. :) Something like Alice often talks to you about her friend Bob, and some day she visits you with a boy, then you invite him 'You _must_ be Bob.'

Comment: It's same mathematical answer as mathematical question. For any given sequence of numbers you can find a reason to put any chosen number as any chosen position. Just use a polynomial interpolation :) Of course one can argue _some_ rules are 'simpler' so 'more probable' (very vague specification) as an answer. But, strictly speaking, no answer is definite and 'the only correct' to this kind of question.