# What is the next Item in the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

There is a sequence described below.What is the missing item

```
0,7,26,63,?,...
```

Comment: $n^3-1$. Do you have an application?

Comment: $$r^3-1$$  right?

Comment: Try http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html

Comment: Well, the missing item is $0$, because$$a_n=\begin{cases}0,&n=1\\7,&n=2\\26,&n=3\\63,&n=4\\a_{n-4},&n\ge 5\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 8):

The missing item is $42$ of course, and the sequence is:

$$a_n=-\frac{41n^4}{12}+\frac{211n^3}{6}-\frac{1435n^2}{12}+\frac{1025n}{6}-83$$

Comment: +1 for giving the ultimate answer to life, the universe and everything. :)

Comment: @Deepak: Haha, that was just my secondary intention here. My primary goal was to imply to OP that there are infinitely many solutions in this type of questions.

Comment: Excellent answer that reflects the fact that, with no more conditions, there can be infinite answers to this kind of questions. +1

Comment: @Joanpemo: Thanks :) I already tried to imply this to OP in a [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805599/131263) of his or her (apparently, the message hasn't quite gone through yet). Too bad that it was closed, and I suppose that this one will be closed as well sooner than later.

Answer (score 2):

General formula to find next term is~ $$x^3-1$$
$$1^3-1=0$$
$$2^3-1=7$$
$$3^4-1=26$$
$$4^3-1=63$$
$$5^3-1=124$$
Upcoming number in sequence is 215